# How do I use other directory to store session data

Tags: php, session

I'm new to PHP, so I don't know how to change default (/temp/) directory to store session data. eg I want to store all session() data in a seperate directory called (/root/sceret_data/). Do I need to change it in .htaccess ? I've no root access as I.m on shared host.

Any help with example please ?

Comment: Why do you need to change the default directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the path with this PHP function:

```
session_save_path();
```

http://at.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php

The path /root is not the best idea. PHP have no write access there.